# PHP - Click button to show array

Tags: php, arrays, button

I pretty new at PHP (also my first question here).

I have created a button, when you click on it I want the values in an array to show up on the page. (And would also like the values to show up randomly everytime you click on the button if possible.)

I do not want to use any JavaScript, only PHP, HTML and CSS.
Any help highly appreciated!

```
$months= array(
"January",
"February",
"March",
"April",
"May",
"June",
"July",
"August",
"September",
"October",
"November",
"December" );


foreach ($months as $month) {
    echo $month . "<br>"; 
}



<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why doesn't any current method work?

Comment: You should wrap your `foreach` output in an `if` statement so that you ask PHP `if` button is pressed then run the `foreach`.

Comment: You can then use `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` [superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) to check the value of the button so `if($_REQUEST['submit'] === "Submit"){...` encases the foreach statement and that's all you really need

Comment: I tried to use an if statement with isset($_POST['submit']). But it did not work. 

Ok, thank you. I did it like this but nothing shows on the page. 

if ($_REQUEST['submit'] === "submit") {
        foreach ($months as $month) {
    echo $month . "<br>";
 }
  
 Not sure what I am doing wrong..

Comment: Is your `<input>` inside a `<form>` element in the HTML?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Sorry that I didn't wrote all of my code and what I already tried! Will do next time! Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `if()` condition to check the name posted and if yes it echoes the array

You can try the following

```
if($_POST['submit'] === 'Submit'){
foreach ($months as $month) {
    echo $month . "<br>"; 
 }
}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

**Note :** Assign the second `Submit` with capital **S** after the operator.

Comment: Thank you! It says "Undefined index: submit." when I do so.

Comment: Then check for the code below this php code because it is not executing the code till `<input>`.Your code is stopping somewhere.

Comment: The code should go till `<input>` and after this too it is giving the error please provide your entire code by editing this question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Sorry that I didn't wrote all of my code and what I already tried! Will do next time! Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Oh sorry, will do! Im new here.